# Invalid operands to binary * ( have 'char *' and 'char **' ) error

Tags: c

I have write simple program as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char* alphabate[]={
  (char *)"xyz",
  (char *)"abc",
  (char *)"pqr",
  NULL
};

void main()
{
    char **pp;

    for( pp=alphabate; *pp; pp++ )
    {
        printf("\n alphabate member %s" *pp);
    }
}
```

but when i compile  it on my Linux machine then it show following error at printf() statement.

```
test.c:19: error: Invalid operands to binary *  ( have 'char *' and 'char **' )
```

Any idea to resolve it?

Comment: Do you really need to cast the string literals? I don't think so. It anyway evaluates to a `char *`

Comment: The signature of `main` should be `int main(void)`

Comment: Need to cast string literals for removing warning related deprecating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
>     printf("\n alphabate member %s" *pp);
> ```

you are missing a comma before *pp

Comment: Thanks tristan..i can't figure out this little mistake

Answer (score 3):

```
printf("\n alphabate member %s" *pp);
```

should be

```
printf("\n alphabate member %s", *pp);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `,` in printf after the `printf("\n alphabate member %s",*pp);`

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <unistd.h>

    char* alphabate[]={
        (char *)"xyz",
        (char *)"abc",
        (char *)"pqr",
        NULL
        };

    int main()
    {
        char **pp;

     for( pp=alphabate; *pp; pp++ )
     {
          printf("\n alphabate member %s",*pp);
     }
      return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a comma missing after the string in printf. It must be

```
 printf("\n alphabate member %s", *pp);
```

With your code, the * is interpreted as multiplication.

Comment: I think yours is the best answer, 'cos you explained the reason too. +1!!

Answer (score 1):

Casting string literals to `char *` is redundant. Also the signature of main in C should be either:

```
int main(void)
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

You are missing a comma in the `printf` function. It should be

```
printf("\n alphabate member %s", *pp);
```